# Apache MQ transportConnectors uri value issue

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic, activemq-cpp

Consider the following code:

```
    <amq:transportConnectors>
        <amq:transportConnector uri="${esb.endpoint}"/>
    </amq:transportConnectors>
```

It is not able to resolve the uri value. The error I am getting is :

```
STACKTRACE:
at com.mincom.util.gadget.Starter.run(Starter.java:40)
THROWABLE: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean
definition with name 'org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService#0' defined in class 
path resource [minestar/esbadapter/service/EsbEmbeddedApacheContext.xml]: Could not 
resolve placeholder 'esb.endpoint' in string value "${esb.endpoint}"; nested exception 
is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'esb.endpoint' in 
string value "${esb.endpoint}"
```

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: where do you set the value of esb.endpoint?

Comment: @CharlieS In jms properties files as: `esb.endpoint=tcp://localhost:61616`

Comment: seems its not finding the property, how do you specify the property file? are any other properties set that are being found?

Comment: @CharlieS I am giving the properties file as this:

`<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>classpath:/jms.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>`

Comment: try giving the full path instead of `classpath:` and see if it helps? do you need the bean or just the properties?

Comment: @CharlieS I need the bean and the properties. As I am trying to make an extension and will deploy it to another system, I cannot hardcode the classpath.

Comment: maybe remove the `/` from the file name instead? `classpath:/` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @CharlieS Will try this and get back to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite evident that spring is unable to find the properties file
easiest way is to see the configuration of properties file

my way is to do it like this:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="required.properties" />
```

for this you will need to add following in your spring namespace

```
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
```

hope it helps,

Good luck!

Comment: will classpath work in place of `location="required.properties"`

Comment: surely, you can do something like <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:required.properties" />